# Would you show me how to save my domain class

Tags: grails

I am still learning Grails.  I am building up my kickoff project little by little.  Please excuse me for so many newbie questions.

The command generate-all creates my book service class.  Grails generates the BookService.  It looks like this.

```
import grails.gorm.services.Service
@Service(Book)
interface BookService {
    Book get(Serializable id)
    List<Book> list(Map args)
    Long count()
    void delete(Serializable id)
    Book save(Book book)
}
```

Grails generates the BookController with a save action that call the service to save my book.

```
bookService.save(book)
```

So far so good.  I can save without any problem.  BUT instead, I replace bookService.save(book) with simply **book.save()** in the save action.  Now, it won't save my book to the database.  I also try **book.save(flush: true)**.  It won't save the book either.

Do you have any idea why book.save() (with or without flush: true) will not save but bookService.save(book) will save?

I don't know what **interface BookService** means in Grails.
Would you teach me where I can add more methods to the BookService please?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save outside transaction is not allowed. Controllers are not transactional. If you want to save in controller then move the save logic in a transaction, like -

```
Book.withTransaction { status ->
  ...
}
```

https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/5.2/migration-guide.adoc#misc

The best practice is to use the `Service` layer for all database related activities.

And for about `interface Service` please have a look at http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html#dataServices

[Grails: How to override generated service method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56825387/grails-how-to-override-generated-service-method)

[Grails 3.3.3 generate-all <domain class> Creates only the Service Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326761/grails-3-3-3-generate-all-domain-class-creates-only-the-service-interface)

Comment: Wow!  That is great!  I would never find any of these pages since I did not know the Grails terminology. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask you another question?  So, generate-all generates a data access service.  It is not the same as this service the document from Grails. Correct? https://docs.grails.org/4.0.5/guide/services.html

Comment: Data access services converted to this service for you at compile time by GORM.